# Как работает DOMparser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, dom, discord

Недавно начал изучать java script, и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня не работает DOMparser. Его задача - это заходить на некоторый сайт и брать оттуда картинку, но он выдает ошибку. Кто шарит помогите пожалуйста.

```
const DomParser = require('dom-parser');
const parser = new DomParser();

let document = parser.parseFromString('ссылка', "text/html");

let imagElem = document.querySelector("body > div.wrapper > div#contentWrapper > div#content > div.content-container > div.container-left > div.user-profile > div.user-image.mb8 > img");
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Comment: А ошибка какая?

Comment: Не может взять инфу со страницы

Comment: Приведите ошибку полностью

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Comment: Ну наверное потому что на вход ему нужно подавать html, а не ссылку.

Comment: Используйте fetch ну или axios если будете работать с фреймворке.
Советую посмотреть видео на ютубе [тык](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKCD9djJQKc)

Answer (score 0):

`DOMParser` парсит веб-элементы из строки, т.е. `string`. На сайт, предоставленный Вами в первом аргументе - `parser.parseFromString('ссылка', ...)` он воспринимает как уже готовый html-документ.

Для получения веб-страницы рекомендую воспользоваться `fetch()` (уже встроен), `request` или `puppeteer` (эмулирует клики, если нужно куда-то нажать, **для автоматизации**)